# Connect Sharepoint List to Sharepoint webpage

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list, saving-data

I am trying to connect a Sharepoint List to Sharepoint webpage and would like to perform below operation by clicking on button

1. Insert data into Sharepoint list
2. Retrieve data into Sharepoint list
3. Modify record in Sharepoint list

Answer (score 0):

We could add the list web part to display a list from your site on a page and customize it with your own title, view, and even size:

[image]

Users can view, filter, sort, and group the list, or go to the list page by clicking See all.

More information:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-the-list-web-part-ef0a1b80-f8b3-443d-b04a-1e76c70b5537